# Integrate Octave with C++ in QtCreator IDE

Tags: c++, c, qt-creator, octave

I am trying to do some DSP operations in C++ using Octave...I have been trying to integrate Octave with QtCreator 5.1 (MinGW compiler) with no success...I have done the following steps...

1. Downloaded Octave3.4.3_gcc4.5.2-install.exe and intsalled in C drive. I have added the address of the bin folder of octave to the environmental variable `PATH`
2. Set the INCLUDEPATH and LIBS according to the location of the header files and the libraries of the Octave directory.
3. [This](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs) is the sample program I am trying to run .
4. The code builds successfully. However while running it hangs up. Debugging yeilds the following message.     [image]
5. I tried to create an executable using the command prompt of octave using the command `mkoctfile --link-stand-alone octavetest.cpp -o octavetest`. The executable created also hangs up with an error message.

   If anyone can point out where exactly I am going wrong in the integrating process it would be realy helpful. Is there any other simple way to set up the environment to call Octave APIs from C++? I have almost checked on the internet forums including stack overflow with no luck...

Comment: Did you try stepping through the application in a debugger line by line? And see, where the `SIGSEGV` occurs?

Comment: just an OT hint: alt + PtrScn ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your gcc/libstdc++ version will likely be incompatible with the one octave got compiled with.

[This compiler](https://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/downloads/detail?name=mingw32-gcc-4.6.2-release-c%2Cc%2B%2B%2Cfortran-dwarf-FINAL.7z&can=2&q=) is as close as i got to the one used to build the [current octave-binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Windows%20binaries/Octave%203.6.4%20for%20Windows%20MinGW%20installer/Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2_20130408.7z/download).

If you extract both archives and add their bin directories to your path variable, you should be able to build octave programs. [Your linked sample](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs) builds for me.

You can also add the compiler in QtCreator. (Tools⇒Options⇒Build&Run)

Answer (score 2):

I have done exactly the same thing on Windows. In my experience, you need to build Octave with exactly the same compiler that you're building your executable with. That's all there's to it. This really means you have to build Octave from sources. I have wasted a lot of time avoiding to build Octave, and in the end could never be sure that it'll be stable or not. Octave will build with VS 2012 with very minor tweaks.

Building Octave is really the only practical way to go, I think. The amount of time you spend setting up an Octave build will insignificant in the long run.